# iTextSharp Created PDF is still in use

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, itext

If i create a pdf with the given source-code, i have the problem that i can not open the pdf-document for example in "adobe-acrobat" because it says that it is still in use by another process. What i am missing in my code to release the lock?

```
var a = Guid.NewGuid();

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

PdfWriter writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(a.ToString()+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
writer2.SetFullCompression();
writer2.CloseStream = true;

iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(AppContext.BaseDirectory + "Ehrungsantrag.png");
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(pdfDoc.PageSize.Height);
img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(pdfDoc.PageSize.Width);
pdfDoc.Open();
pdfDoc.NewPage();
pdfDoc.Add(img);

pdfDoc.Close();
writer2.Close();
```

Comment: Are you sure this code runs without exception?  If you get an error, your streams won't be closed because they aren't in a `using`.

Comment: IDisposable objects should be closed and disposed

Comment: @bradbury9 theoretically yes but `PdfWriter` incorrectly implements the underlying pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was not closed FileStream. Also as @Amy already mentioned, you need be sure that your clean up code is executed, for example like this:

```
Document pdfDoc = null;
PdfWriter writer2 = null;
System.IO.FileStream fs = null; // <- create the FileStream

try
{
   var a = Guid.NewGuid();
   pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

   fs =  new FileStream(a.ToString()+".pdf", FileMode.Create);
   writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs);
   writer2.SetFullCompression();
   writer2.CloseStream = true;

   iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(AppContext.BaseDirectory + "Ehrungsantrag.png");
   img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
   img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(pdfDoc.PageSize.Height);
   img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(pdfDoc.PageSize.Width);

   pdfDoc.Open();
   pdfDoc.NewPage();
   pdfDoc.Add(img);
}
finally
{
        pdfDoc.Close();
        pdfDoc = null;

        //writer2.Close(); 

       // That was the eroor -> always close open filehandles explicity !
       fs.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: if i try this provided solution it doesnt effect my problem - still got this error when i try open the pdf:

'the file can not be opened because it is being used by another proess. Please close all applications that might access this file and try again.'

Comment: Yes of course - there is no error. But the document is still like blocked in the creation process.

Comment: Awful exception handling. Also, no need to set a variable to `null`. Better use the `IDisposable` pattern.

Comment: It is completely unnecessary. Never handle locally, always handle globally or if you _really_ need to locally.

Comment: Then remove the `catch` and leave the `finally`. Makes it clearer, too.

Comment: There is no need to close the writer after the document in the `finally` block - the document itself closes the writer. The `PdfWriter` incorrectly implements the `IDisposable` interface.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = Guid.NewGuid();

using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f))
using (var writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(a.ToString()+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
{
    writer2.SetFullCompression();
    writer2.CloseStream = true;

    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(AppContext.BaseDirectory + "Ehrungsantrag.png");
    img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(pdfDoc.PageSize.Height);
    img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(pdfDoc.PageSize.Width);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.NewPage();
    pdfDoc.Add(img);
}
```

Comment: No need for those `Close()` calls at the end when using `IDisposable` pattern.

Comment: Please don't put the `PdfWriter` of itext versions before 7 into a `using`. Yes, it implements `IDisposable` but falsely so. By architecture it is expected to be closed indirectly by the `Document` (`PdfWriter.GetInstance` accordingly injects the instances). If it is closed before the `Document`, some content may be missing in the result pdf.